# Can't update products and attributes in Magento 1.9.2.2

Tags: magento-1.9, product, attributes, product-attribute, backend

We just recently moved our Magento 1.9.2.2 site to a new server. We tried a few tests and noticed that we can't update products and attributes in the backend. The page refreshes but there is no success message. We checked our error_logs and this is the error:

```
2016-04-08T09:01:33+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given  in /var/www/vhosts/xxx/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php on line 507
2016-04-08T09:01:33+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given  in /var/www/vhosts/xxx/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php on line 507
2016-04-08T09:01:33+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given  in /var/www/vhosts/xxx/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php on line 507
2016-04-08T09:01:33+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given  in /var/www/vhosts/xxx/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php on line 507
2016-04-08T09:01:33+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given  in /var/www/vhosts/xxx/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php on line 507
2016-04-08T09:01:33+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given  in /var/www/vhosts/xxx/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php on line 507
2016-04-08T09:01:33+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Varien_Object::addData() must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/vhosts/xxx/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php on line 514 and defined  in /var/www/vhosts/xxx/xxx/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 243
2016-04-08T09:01:33+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in /var/www/vhosts/xxx/xxx/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 245
```

We have tried running the compiler as well as clearing the cache but it didn't work.

Anyone that can help me out with this is much, much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like you're not the only one to face the problem: https://community.magento.com/t5/Technical-Issues/Can-t-edit-or-save-existing-product/td-p/17261

Comment: I tried that fix earlier, but I don't think it has something to do with the extensions since the site was working properly on our previous server with no extensions disabled :(

Comment: Has anyone ever encountered this? I've had this problem for 3 weeks now. I tried this solution but it didn't work for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32671443/cant-edit-save-and-existing-product-in-magento/32683262

Comment: Which version of PHP are you running ?

Comment: I'm using version 5.4.45